# Question about Vanitygen performance

Tags: vanitygen, performance

I just read a [blog](https://0day.work/using-an-aws-gpu-instance-to-generate-vanity-bitcoin-addresses/) about someone rent an AWS hpc & run Vanitygen to get a vanity address & some of the [latest 2018 performance](https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/9aqu7m/use_of_vanitygen_to_try_to_attack_addresses/). Assume i have some of the top supercomputer these days(Sierra, Summit, Titan,...) & to get the address 1BitcoinEater... . How many key can it generate per second, like summit specifically? How long does it take to get the address i want?

Comment: Generating keypairs on a cloud server is a bad idea, security-wise. Usually you would want to keep your private keys as secure as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summit supercomputer has:

9,216 POWER9 22-core CPUs

Using CPU we have total 202752 cores to run, Vanitygen automatically use all threads to calculate, on average a CPU can generate 250k keys/sec on Vanitygen. Multiply & we have about 506Gkeys/sec, this is way lower than i expected. I don't know how to calculate time to generate the key you mention though